Is there a way to use glfwSetScrollCallback function inside a class?
Hello I'm following opengl tutorial from this page and trying to implement a camera class.
Here's my camera class code.
class Camera
{
public:
    
    static float fov;
    glm::vec3 pos;
    glm::vec3 front;
    glm::vec3 up;

    bool firstMouse;
    float screen_width;
    float screen_height;


    Camera(float screen_width, float screen_height);
    ~Camera();

    
    void setup_scroll_inputs(GLFWwindow* window);
    static void scroll_callback_static(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
};

and cpp
void Camera::setup_scroll_inputs(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, Camera::scroll_callback_static);
}
void Camera::scroll_callback_static(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    fov -= (float)yoffset;
    if (fov < 20.0f)
        fov = 20.0f;
    if (fov > 100.0f)
        fov = 100.0f;
    
}

What I want to achieve is zoom-in and zoom-out feature whenever I scroll up or down.
I tried to put glfwSetScrollCallback function in the camera class member function because
I want to keep my main function as clean as possible.
My scroll_callback function has to be a static member function since glfwSetScrollCallback is expecting a function pointer.
However, I want to make it possible for the scroll_callback function to access camera's member variables.
Is there a way to achieve this?
At the moment, I made fov to be a static member variable since my scrollback function would not have access to it otherwise.

Check if GLFWwindow supports storing some user data. If so you can store your this pointer in it, and then use it in the callback (extract from the window parameter) to call your class method.

A static function won't be able to access members of the class. You can use a non-capturing lambda to connect it
To access your camera object you'll need to store a pointer to it using glfwSetWindowUserPointer and retrieve it inside the lambda using glfwGetWindowUserPointer
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, &camera);
glfwSetScrollCallback(window, [](GLFWwindow* window,double xoffset, double yoffset) { 
    Camera* camera = (Camera*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    camera->scroll_callback(window, xoffset, yoffset); 
});


glfwSetScrollCallback() requires a C-style function pointer, but a capturing lambda is not compatible with that.

Indeed, I corrected it

Use glfwSetWindowUserPointer() to store the Camera object's this pointer inside the GLFWwindow object, and then your callback can use glfwGetWindowUserPointer() to get the pointer back.
void Camera::setup_scroll_inputs(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, this);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, Camera::scroll_callback_static);
}

void Camera::scroll_callback_static(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    Camera *this = (Camera*) glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    ...    
}

